# How to register a ContraintValidator with MockMvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I know this was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35410514/how-to-inject-a-bean-in-a-constraintvalidator-with-mockmvc), but that was never really answered satisfactory.

How do you add a [`ContstraintValidator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) with MockMvc?

I expected to find something on the [`StandaloneMockMvcBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.html), as I was able to use it to add an argument resolver, but I don't see anything for it. There is [`setValidator()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.html#setValidator-org.springframework.validation.Validator-) but that doesn't support a `javax.validation.ContstraintValidator`.

Comment: That question does answer it, use a proper configuration to configure `MockMvc`.